# Div contents pushing down adjacent divs

Tags: html, css

I have three adjacent divs of equal width and I'm trying to figure out why the contents of the first, which has an additional button inside, pushes down the other two divs. Is it a display issue? I'd rather understand the cause before trying to manually top-align them. Thanks!

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="events-cont">
        <div class="events-row">
          <div class="event-card">
              <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
              <div class="event-card-info">
              <h1>Event title</h1>
              <h2>Event date</h2>
              <h2>Event venue</h2>
              <p>
                Event description
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
              </p>
              <a class="tickets-button" href="#">Buy Tickets</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="event-card">
              <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
              <div class="event-card-info">
              <h1>Event title</h1>
              <h2>Event date</h2>
              <h2>Event venue</h2>
              <p>
                Event description
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="event-card">
              <img src="http://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=36&txt=Event%20Photo&w=382&h=275" />
              <div class="event-card-info">
              <h1>Event title</h1>
              <h2>Event date</h2>
              <h2>Event venue</h2>
              <p>
                Event description
                <a href="#">Learn More</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#events-cont {
  padding: 30px 0;

  .events-row {
    .event-card {
      padding: 0 15px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 33%;

      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .event-card-info {
        padding: 15px;
        min-height: 300px;
        text-align: left;
        background: #ededed;

        .tickets-button {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 30px;
          padding: 10px 30px;
          font-size: 1.8em;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/eBWxLz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.event-card`s are `inline-block` so they are by default vertically aligned to the baseline.

Use `vertical-align: top` on the `.event-card` class:

```
.event-card {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBKwPO

Answer (score 1):

Because the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`. This should fix it.

```
.event-card {
  ...
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would float the divs. Update this part of your CSS:

```
#events-cont .events-row .event-card {
    padding: 0 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    float: left; //added to stop the divs from being pushed down.
}
```